# Regarding Views in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

With model binding it looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>StudentRegistration</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

and in simple Html:

```
<form>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
    Radio Button: Are you male or female?<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
</form>
```

My question is: while writing views for the models should I have to wrap the model name with the fields or I can plainly write html code in the views? I am using Entity Framework as DB.

Comment: both works i think, you can give it a try, but make sure to name the fields same as your Model fields name

Comment: What happens when you try?  What is stopping your attempt from working as expected?

Comment: You can write simple HTML in views, but this is a very bad practice overall - you lose coupling between your view, ViewModel and Controller and make this view very difficult to maintain and refactor

Comment: Entity Framework is not a DB - it's a **DB access** component - but it's not a database itself.

Answer (score 1):

First, your HTML version is *not* the same at all. The equivalent would be something more like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_RequestVerificationToken" value="XXXXXX" />

    <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName">
    <span class="validation-error">...</span>

    ...
</form>
```

That's extremely simplified, but it points out a few things:

1. The form action will be set appropriately so that the post is sent to the right place, instead of you hardcoding where it should go.
2. A request verification token is added to the form to prevent CSRF, which you would be vulnerable to otherwise.
3. Your label text is actually wrapped by a `label` element, and the `for` attribute is set appropriately so that it will actually connect with the input, instead of you having to hardcode this, or (in your case) losing the functionality altogether.
4. The input is given appropriate `name` and `id` attribute values, so that it can both be connected to a label, and be properly bound on post, instead of you having to hardcode all this.

I made of point of emphasizing the fact that you would have to hardcode a lot of things if you just manually write all the HTML yourself. That's important because by using the helpers, Razor will propagate changes in your C# code to your HTML and let you know if things like property names have changed, or properties have been removed entirely.

If you hardcode all your HTML, you get none of this. Things will just silently break. Fields won't be rendered that should be. Values that should be posted will be discarded. You will 100% responsible for keeping your HTML and C# code in sync at all times, and if you've done development for any length of time, you should be familiar with one of its most basic precepts: anything that requires human intervention *will* fail, because humans fail. You *will* forget. You *will* miss something. You *will* screw something up. Those are all givens. Using Razor helpers means you get to remove some of that human fallibility, which is always a good thing.